# Get the Keys in Hash of Array - Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script where i need to work on Keys of HASH and i am struggling to extract all the keys of HASH. Here is my Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %HOA = (
                "age" => [20 ,25],
                "Name" => ["Raj" ,"Kiran"]
            );

foreach my $key ( keys%HOA){
print "Key -> $HOA{$key}\n";
my @array = @{$HOA{$key}};
    foreach my $val (@array){
        print "val -> $val\n";
}
}
```

I need to store all the keys in an array. Can some on help me out?

Comment: `keys %HOA` should give you all the keys. Did you mean to say that you want all array elements from the values of the hash?

Comment: Thanks :) this what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you all the array elements from the hash in one array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %HOA = (
    "age" => [20 ,25],
    "Name" => ["Raj" ,"Kiran"]
    );

my @array=map @{$HOA{$_}},keys %HOA;

foreach my $val (@array)
    {
    print "$val\n";
    }
```

Comment: Why bother with the keys at all? `@array = map { @$_ } values(%HOA)`

Comment: Or even `say for map { @$_ } values(%HOA)`, although I don't claim that the second one is very readable.